# how to add empty image to table

Tags: c#, winforms

I want if user do not set image for picturebox save empy image in table .

my code is :

```
 byte[] arrImage;
 if (picperson.Image != null)
 {
     //convert image to byte
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     picperson.Image.Save(ms, picperson.Image.RawFormat);
     arrImage = ms.GetBuffer();
     ms.Close();
 }
 else arrImage = null;

objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", arrImage);
```

when he adds null image, exception occurs on line picperson.Image.Save(ms, picperson.Image.RawFormat);

How to add empty imag to table ?

---

Comment: Choose any image, and add it when you need to add null... simple !!

Comment: Good grief... I have no idea what this person is saying. I know I'm not great in English, but still. "But when I want add error"... What does that mean?

Comment: size of table become High !!!

Comment: @LightStriker It means when he adds `null` image, exception occurs on line `picperson.Image.Save(ms, picperson.Image.RawFormat);`

Comment: visual studio Highlight on picperson.Image.Save(ms, picperson.Image.RawFormat)

Comment: @Shaharyar What exception? Normally, when you want some information about an exception, you post the message related to this exception.

Comment: @LightStriker Well ! you are right.. But did not ask it :)

Comment: picperson.Image.Save(ms, picperson.Image.RawFormat) .because this error is in picperson.image where picperson.image is empty and have not image .

Comment: Your code should work perfectly.As it is already handling the null problem.If there is no image the code will not execute.

Comment: Your code does not match your description of the problem. In your code, when the image is null, you save an empty array to the database. However, in your questions, you have mentioned that you want to save an empty image. Those are two entirely different things. What do you really want to do?

Comment: this code do not work .

Comment: you should make an image with some bytes in it using GDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a null value for your image parameter, so a work around would be to send in a zero byte array:

```
if (picperson.Image != null) {
     //convert image to byte
} else {
 arrImage = new byte[0];
}
```

Unfortunately, that will not set the field to null.

To set the field to null would probably be handled best with a separate query, for example:

```
using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO M (MyImage) VALUES (null)", cn)
...
```

which does not use parameters.

As far as reading some of the comments are concerned, it sounds like the image format needs to be specified.  Try using the actual format that you want the image saved as:

```
picperson.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
// or
picperson.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // or Png, etc.
```

Comment: this code work correctly but when I want see table in datagridview error.

Comment: @anfd That sounds like a new question.  Please try to post it with proper documentation, like the error message, and if possible, enough code that your readers can understand the issue at hand.  Of course, try to research it first to see if the issue has been previously addressed.